# How to create Top-level Qt rounded widget on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

When I create rounded Qt top-level widget, it creates invisible rectangle background and I can't select file `123` under widget:

[image: How to select file 123]

This is constructor of my MainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : // where MainWindow - QMainWindow
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

  ui->setupUi(this);

  QBitmap mask(size());
  mask.clear();
  QPainter p(&mask);
  p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
  p.setPen(QColor(Qt::black));
  p.setBrush(QColor(Qt::black));
  p.drawRoundedRect(geometry(), 200, 200, Qt::AbsoluteSize);
  setMask(mask);
}
```

This code works on Windows. I can select file `123` there.
How to remove that invisible background rectangle?

Comment: It's a shortcoming of the Qt implementation on OS X. Fixing it would require patching the Gui module. What is your version of Qt and OS X?